# How to add parameters into an [ MQL4 ] function through an Array?

Tags: function, parameters, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I want to build a function for some code that I use often in my **`MQL4`** programming that outputs to a file data resulting from optimisation runs.

I already have the working code but I am having a difficulty with passing parameters.

Some of the function parameters, that I need to access inside the function and so these need to be passed as parameters, are global, user defined variables - eg as:
 **`input int Moving_Average_period = .... ;`**.

The next time I use the function, this variable may not be required but another(s) will

This variable reference needs to appear in a **`FileWrite()`** statement eg:

```
FileWrite( h, Counter, Moving_Average_period, StopLoss, .......... );
```

any ideas please - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Declare the function with an Array(s) in the call-signature:

Simply put,

```
void aFunctionWithValuesInARRAYs(  int      const anArrayOfINTs[],
                                   double   const anArrayOfDOUBLEs[],
                                   datetime const anArrayOfDATETIMEs[]
                                   ) {
  // ------------------------               ^
  // PROCESS DATA AS YOU NEED               +-- pre-loading and updating values
  // ------------------------                   in each anArrayOf*s[] is a very
  // Q.E.D.                                     flexible external-responsibility
     ...
}
```